# Is it possible to know if a variable is a reference at compile time in Rust?

Tags: rust

Given the following code:

```
fn main() {
    let a: i32 = 1;
    let b: &i32 = &a;
    let c: String = "hello world".to_string();
    let d: &str = &c[..];
}
```

I know

- `a` is well a normal variable that holds a value,
- `b` is a reference that holds a pointer
- `c` is a reference, although a smart one, because apart from holding the pointer it contains other data like length, capacity, etc.
- `d` is a reference, not a smart one, but what I see often referred to as fat pointer. It contains the pointer and simple extra info like length of the data pointed to.

Ok, so now my question is, is there a way to inspect these variables or these types at compile time to know which kind of reference they are?

I know there are couple of functions that can be used to introspect types. Like `std::mem::size_of` and `std::mem::align_of`. I was wondering are there ones that can be use to deduce what kind of reference something is?

Comment: I don't get it. All type information is already available at compile time. You say so yourself. You already know what kind of a reference everything is, you listed them beneath the code snippet. What exactly is the extra info you want to know about these types?

Comment: > "`a` is well a normal variable that holds a value" Yes, and so are `b`, `c`, and `d`. The values have different types, but they are all "normal variables" (whatever that means).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems, that you don't quite understand what references are in rust-land. Your description suggest that you have a very similar understanding of what a reference is in C++, but here in rust it's all very different.

In rust references are **types**. `T`, `&T` and `&mut T` are three different types. They are similar to pointers, but have additional guarantees, of which most important are:

- they are **never** null
- they do not outlive data to which they point to
- there can be only one mutable reference or any number of shared references to a given object at one time

You can have also references to other references (just like in C you can have a pointer to a pointer), so `T`, `&T`, `&&T`, `&&&T`, etc. are different types.

Now when we say that something is a reference it means that it's **type** is some kind of reference. So in the following code

```rust
fn main() {
    let a: i32 = 1;
    let b: &i32 = &a;
    let c: String = "hello world".to_string();
    let d: &str = &c[..];
}
```

- `a` has a type `i32` (a singed integer)
- `b` has a type `&i32` and thus it's a reference to a number
- `c` has a type `String` and it is **not** a reference. Internally it contains a pointer to heap allocated buffer of course, but type of `String` is just `String`, not a reference to any other type
- `d` has a type `&str` and is a reference. More specifically it is a reference to a string [slice](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-03-slices.html). As you pointed out it is a "fat" pointer, because it contains not only the address of the beginning of a slice, but also it's length.

So finally addressing your question. There are only two kinds of references in rust, shared `&T` and exclusive (or mutable) `&mut T`. Since all types must be know at the compile time you don't have any runtime introspection or reflection functions that would tell you what kind of a reference is some type. There is not such thing as "smart references" in rust, but there is something called [smart pointers](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-00-smart-pointers.html), although it is something very different.

Comment: "but there is something called smart pointers, although it is something very different" But will it be correct to say Strings are smart pointers?

Comment: I think the difference between something like String (a Smart pointer) and something like $str a Fat pointer, is that with a Smart pointer, the value is "owned" so String owns its value...with a Fat pointer, the value is not owned (its a reference) so $str does not own the value...it only references it

Comment: @FinlayWeber You can call `String` a *"smart pointer"* if you like for the reasons you mentioned above though conventionally its not common to do so. Typically you would call `Box`, `Arc`, `Rc`, *"smart pointers"* because they are only used for their pointer-like properties and the *"smart"* ownership semantics around that pointer. A `String` does that but a lot more since it provides additional capacity and resizing capabilities. What I'm getting at is a `String` is more than just a pointer, practically speaking.

Comment: @kmdreko from the link about smart pointer that you shared:

> Though we didn't call them as such at the time, we’ve already encountered a few smart pointers in this book, including String and Vec<T> in Chapter 8. Both these types count as smart pointers because they own some memory and allow you to manipulate it. They also have metadata and extra capabilities or guarantees. String, for example, stores its capacity as metadata and has the extra ability to ensure its data will always be valid UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want to know what a reference points to, then you can use the `ToOwned` trait (Ex: `<str as ToOwned>::Owned` would evaluate to `String`). However, it sounds to me what you may want is a [`Cow<'a, T>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/enum.Cow.html). Their name stands for Clone On Write. At their core they are simply an enum of either a reference or an owned value.

```rust
pub enum Cow<'a, B> 
where
    B: 'a + ToOwned + ?Sized, 
{
    Borrowed(&'a B),
    Owned(<B as ToOwned>::Owned),
}
```

They can be extremely helpful for operations on strings and slices where you may need to modify the input, but do not want to copy all of the data if the input is already valid. The main benefit is they can be treated as owned values, but give you the flexibility to switch between the two based on performance.

```rust
use std::borrow::Cow;

pub fn remove_fives(slice: &[i32]) -> Cow<[i32]> {
    if slice.iter().any(|x| *x == 5) {
        // We found some 5s to remove so we need to clone the input and remove them
        // from the result. This creates a new Vec<i32> we can modify.
        let mut owned_values = slice.to_owned();
        owned_values.retain(|x| *x != 5);
        
        Cow::Owned(owned_values)
    } else {
        // No fives were found so no we don't need to allocate anything or do extra work
        Cow::Borrowed(slice)
    }
}
```

As a fun side point, if we interpret just the title of the question it is not too difficult to write a simple `is_ref<T>()` function that is resolved to a value at compile time. It uses traits in a similar manor to the far more helpful [`impls`](https://crates.io/crates/impls) crate. This can be interesting, but probably is not all that helpful.

```rust
pub const fn is_ref<T: ?Sized>() -> bool {
    trait IsNotRef {
        const IS_REF: bool = false;
    }
    
    impl<A: ?Sized> IsNotRef for A {}
    
    struct Wrapper<A: ?Sized>(::std::marker::PhantomData<A>);
    
    impl<'a, A: ?Sized> Wrapper<&'a A> {
        const IS_REF: bool = true;
    }
    
    impl<'a, A: ?Sized> Wrapper<&'a mut A> {
        const IS_REF: bool = true;
    }
    
    <Wrapper<T>>::IS_REF
}
```